# filter dataframe by contents in name vector R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

i have a dataframe (lu) and a vector of names (df.names). i want to create a df that retains all rows whose names are in my vector.

im trying `dplyr::filter()` as you can see in my code bellow:

```
lu.names <- lu %>% filter(df.names)
```

but this line of code returns said error:

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. 
i Input `..1` is `df.names`. 
x Input `..1` must be of size 24 or 1, not size 22.
```

Comment: Can you share reproducible example using `dput` function

Comment: Try `lu[,names(lu) %in% df.names]` (assuming lu is the data.frame and df.names is the vector with names)

Comment: this worked, but `rownames()` instead of `names()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one here (I created a simple data.frame and vector with names).

```
library(dplyr)

#create a simple and reproducible example
df <- data.frame(a = runif(20), b = runif(20), row.names = letters[1:20])
names <- letters[seq(1,20, 2)]

df_filtered <- df %>%
    filter(row.names(df) %in% names)
```